# If the element is defined by its class the font-size works incorrect

Tags: html, css, html-table, font-size

I was making a project, where i had to change font size of an element and it works differently. 
For example, i have a code

```
<div class="text-area-1">
            <h2>We are <span class="span1">Newbie</span></h2>
</div>
```

and in CSS i set

```
text-area-1{
  font-size:60px;}
```

The font-size doesn`t feel like 60px, it looks like it is 80px+ size, but when rewrite it differently:

```
h2, span{ font-size: 60px}
```

now it's truly 60px.Can somebody explain me, why it happens? Doesn't setting a property to a parent(div) set the same property for other children(h2, span)?

Comment: Is `text-area-1` the ID of an element, or a CSS class name? If an ID, it should be `#text-area-1`; if a CSS class name, it should be `.text-area-1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Doesn't setting a property to a parent(div) set the same property for other children(h2, span)?

For a `span`, yes it does. That is because `span` is a generic element. From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) page on the `span` element:

> The HTML  element is a generic inline container for phrasing content, which does not inherently represent anything.

The span therefore has no specific font-size defined for it, and it inherits its font-size from its parent.

But a `h2` has a certain font-size defined on the browser's default style sheet (that is the whole point of the tag, apart from some other SEO purposes). When an element has styles appplied to it directly, it no longer inherits this property from its parent.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have the list of elements of these tricky elements, like h2?

Comment: @NotoriousZet I'm glad I could help! A full list of default browser styles can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp If you scroll down to `h2`, you will see a list of properties defined for it, including `font-size`. But for `span`, it just says "None."

Comment: @Run_Script is correct, but the style of the parent can still affect the style of the h2 like it does in this case. The default font-size for a h2 element is 1.5em (in chrome on a macbook), so if you set the font-size of the parent to 60px, the font of the h2 will become 90px (60 x 1.5).